# jQuery: how to match all elements with certain class that follow an element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's my HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <td>data 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="test">
  <td>test data 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="test">
  <td>test data 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>data 2</td>
</tr>
```

The first `<tr>` is assigned to `"var myVar"`. How do I remove all subsequent `<tr>` elements that contain the `"test"` class until I reach the next `<tr>` element? Wrapping them in SPAN/DIV or doing global match on `".test"` is NOT an option.

```
$(myVar)......? :)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Bingo, jensgram got it spon on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(myVar).nextUntil("tr:not(.test)").remove()
```

Comment: Great. I didn't know about the nextUntil. Thanks.